# How to find all combinations of picking one item from the first list and at most n items from the second list

Tags: python, list, combinations, python-itertools

I have two lists and I want to return a new list of lists where each list is from picking exactly one item from the first list and **at most** 2 items from the second list:
from instance:

```
vaccinate_list: [('vaccinate', (2, 3)), ('vaccinate', (8, 1))]
quarantine_list: [('quarantine', (6, 3)), ('quarantine', (3, 4)), ('quarantine', (0, 1))]
```

will return (without the new line):

```
allCombinations = [
[('vaccinate', (2, 3))], 
[('vaccinate', (8, 1))], 
[('vaccinate', (2, 3)), ('quarantine', (6, 3))], 
[('vaccinate', (2, 3)), ('quarantine', (3, 4))], 
[('vaccinate', (2, 3)), ('quarantine', (0, 1))], 
[('vaccinate', (8, 1)), ('quarantine', (6, 3))], 
[('vaccinate', (8, 1)), ('quarantine', (3, 4))], 
[('vaccinate', (8, 1)), ('quarantine', (0, 1))], 
[('vaccinate', (2, 3)), ('quarantine', (6, 3)), ('quarantine', (3, 4))], 
[('vaccinate', (2, 3)), ('quarantine', (6, 3)), ('quarantine', (0, 1))], 
[('vaccinate', (2, 3)), ('quarantine', (3, 4)), ('quarantine', (0, 1))], 
[('vaccinate', (8, 1)), ('quarantine', (6, 3)), ('quarantine', (3, 4))], 
[('vaccinate', (8, 1)), ('quarantine', (6, 3)), ('quarantine', (0, 1))], 
[('vaccinate', (8, 1)), ('quarantine', (3, 4)), ('quarantine', (0, 1))]
]
```

I tried with intertools combinations and struggled,
Help pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way is to use itertools.product. See below (explanation in comments):

```
allCombinations=[]

allCombinations.extend(vaccinate_list) #add items of vaccinate_list only

list_one=[i for i in itertools.product(vaccinate_list, quarantine_list)] #get all combinations with one item from each list

allCombinations.extend(list_one) #add them to allcombinations

list_two_temp=[i for i in itertools.combinations(quarantine_list, 2)] #get combinations of 2, in quarantine_list

list_two=[i for i in itertools.product(vaccinate_list, list_two_temp)] #get combinations with 1 item from vaccinate_list and 2 from quarantine_list

list_two=[(i[0],i[1][0], i[1][1]) for i in list_two] #flatten the items from previous list

allCombinations.extend(list_two) #add them to allcombinations

allCombinations=[list(i) for i in allCombinations] #change all items to list

print(allCombinations)
```

Output:

```
[['vaccinate', (2, 3)], ['vaccinate', (8, 1)], [('vaccinate', (2, 3)), ('quarantine', (6, 3))], [('vaccinate', (2, 3)), ('quarantine', (3, 4))], [('vaccinate', (2, 3)), ('quarantine', (0, 1))], [('vaccinate', (8, 1)), ('quarantine', (6, 3))], [('vaccinate', (8, 1)), ('quarantine', (3, 4))], [('vaccinate', (8, 1)), ('quarantine', (0, 1))], [('vaccinate', (2, 3)), ('quarantine', (6, 3)), ('quarantine', (3, 4))], [('vaccinate', (2, 3)), ('quarantine', (6, 3)), ('quarantine', (0, 1))], [('vaccinate', (2, 3)), ('quarantine', (3, 4)), ('quarantine', (0, 1))], [('vaccinate', (8, 1)), ('quarantine', (6, 3)), ('quarantine', (3, 4))], [('vaccinate', (8, 1)), ('quarantine', (6, 3)), ('quarantine', (0, 1))], [('vaccinate', (8, 1)), ('quarantine', (3, 4)), ('quarantine', (0, 1))]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in vaccinate_list:
    all_combinations.append(i)
for i in vaccinate_list:
    for j in quarantine_list:
         all_combinations.append((i,j))
for i in vaccinate_list:
     for j in quarantine_list:
          for k in quarantine_list:
               all_combinations.append((i, j, k))
```

Might be complicated and might be a dumb way to do it but it works

Comment: This doesn't produce the desired output.